# User credential is different from the current user google app engine java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I tried to login to my app on google app engine using gmail A, but then I switch account to gmail B, but when I open my app again, it still using google credential for gmail A, not for B. How can I make GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder to store the correct credential for the current user?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have some code?

Comment: Hi Gonzalo, it's like this http://pastebin.com/4BhVxPLg. But when I close my window and use different google account, the user id changed, but the credential still the same.

Comment: When you log in and authenticate using your Google account A, *your application* sets a cookie that is associated to that account. From that point on, the Google account you use outside your application (ie, when browsing other Google properties) has nothing to do with the identity you assume when going to your application, which is based on your earlier login with account A.

Comment: Hi Gonzalo, thanks for your explanation. How to get this cookie on app engine? or how to delete it every time user close their browser for the app? thanks.